# post curl into any file from my server get code 400

Tags: php, curl

I got a new server. I wanted to check if the curl works so I've made 2 files - one that does print_r($_SERVER), and the other that does curl to the first file:

```
<?php
 error_reporting('E_ALL');
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/printServer.php';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1 ));

$content = curl_exec($curl);

print $content;

?>
```

and the outcome is

> Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand. Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered
>   while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When I change this curl to be get - it does work...
Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: its work fine on my system. so its better to check error logs

Comment: @SoniVimal I'm happy that it works on your system. There's something wrong with the php / server configurations which is wrong and blocking the POST request... Do you know anything about it?

Comment: enable error reporting ***error_reporting('E_ALL');*** or you can check server error logs

Comment: @SoniVimal already set, with ini_set('display_errors', true);

Comment: add it here above your code

Comment: @SoniVimal still I got no idea how to fix that.

Comment: can you provide me the complete url of your server I want to try in my system

Comment: here maybe one reason is , are you using CURLOPT_POST but not send post data. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is missing